Copy multiple things on mac
I wanted to copy and paste multiple things on macOS.

Cliptool isn’t updated recently. (Nor could I download it.)
flycut, which works fine, but doesn't do what I need.

My requirements are:

be keyboard navigable
handle formatted text preserving it faithfully

I'll mainly use it on word for math equations, so if I copy something from an equation and paste, normally it will paste as an equation, and flycut doesn't do that, at least it only does it if you do the normal paste. if anyone knows of another app that does what I want, or a way to fix flycut, i'd appreciate it.
What apps are workable   for this purpose?

Welcome to Ask Different. I am not sure I understand your requirements totally. Are you looking for a feature to accumulate multiple copies into a single paste? https://obdev.at/support/launchbar?pid=lb&search=Clipboard or perhaps do you want to copy 5 times sequentially pushing them on a stack, then popping them off one at a time with 5 different pastes? Or perhaps you need different clipboards like keyboard maestro can do?

Until you can edit in some details, this is covered by an existing question. We will need more details to understand why the existing many answers don’t suit your problem.
